# Возможно ли более четко разделить обязанности классов?

Tags: java, архитектура

Изучаю Java, делаю серверную часть своей игры, моя задача на данный момент - сделать backend, REST-сервис для общения с игровым клиентом.

Есть класс Browser -  браузер "битв", где игрок может посмотреть созданные битвы ожидающие противников, отсортировать их (скажем, по длительности битвы или уровню профессионализма оппонента) и, выбрав, присоединиться к "битве".

```
public class Browser {
    private static final List<User> subscribers = ...;
    private static final List<PreparedBattle> battles = ...;

    public void subscribe() {...}
    public void unsubscribe() {...}
    ...
    public void createBattle(User creator, ...) {...}
    public void connect(int battleId) {...}
}
```

И тут есть проблемка - например, в методе `createBattle` я должен вернуть текущему юзеру подробную информацию о созданной им битве. А остальным игрокам из `subscribers` мне нужно вернуть просто общую инфу "создана новая битва, id = 55, время битвы 10 мин".

Меня волнует архитектурный вопрос - правильно ли подготавливать и рассылать сообщения прямо из этого класса?
Ведь он отвечает за логику приложения - создает битвы, стартует их. Не его обязанность готовить сообщения - создателю одно, остальным другое, потом может и еще что-то добавится такими темпами. Первый же из принципов SOLID говорит что так не надо делать и это разумно.

Выносить функционал общения с User в отдельный класс тоже особо не поможет, как ни крути, сообщение формировать надо все равно в `Browser`.

Также буду рад если укажете хорошую книгу где рассматриваются такие вопросы, желательно с примерами на Java.

Comment: `сообщение формировать надо все равно в Browser` - почему? Допустим, есть класс `BattleNotifier`, подписанный на `Browser` (иной вид подписки, не имеющийся список `subscribers`). В уведомлении об изменении `BattleNotifier` получает созданную битву и на основании информации о ней рассылает пользователям нужную информацию.

Comment: Получается, нам надо иметь много реализаций некоего интерфейса `Notifier`. `BattleNotifier` будет отправлять инфо о битве: `notifyAll(PreparedBattle battle)`. Но юзеров надо уведомлять еще много о чем - о покупке в магазине, о сообщении в чате и т.д. Придется заводить всякие `ChatNotifier` и т.д. Вроде хороший вариант, отдельная прослойка формирования сообщений.

Answer (score 0):

В общем, существует так называемый паттерн "Наблюдатель" (Observer). Существует много готовых решений реализующих этот паттерн. Например библиотеки реактивности,такие как RxJava и Project Reactor. Также, для вместо обычного http соединения можно использовать более продвинутый Websocket.

Comment: Да, я в курсе, наблюдатель здесь и реализован (поле `subscribers`). Но проблему это не решает, половина кода (а то и больше) в методах все равно формирует ответное сообщение. Websocket тоже ничем не поможет здесь, это лишь смена протокола, шило на мыло.